# Find dictionary keys with duplicate values

Tags: python, dictionary

```
some_dict = {"firstname": "Albert", "nickname": "Albert", "surname": "Likins", "username": "Angel"}
```

I would like to return the keys of my dict where their value exists for more than one time.

Could some one show me how to implement this?

```
a_list = []
for k,v in  some_dict.iteritems():
    if v in some_dict.values() and v != some_dict.keys(k):
        a_list.append(k)
```

Comment: @Blender Sure I have mine here

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First, flip the dictionary around into a reverse multidict, mapping each value to all of the keys it maps to. Like this:

```
>>> some_dict = {"firstname":"Albert","nickname":"Albert","surname":"Likins","username":"Angel"}
>>> rev_multidict = {}
>>> for key, value in some_dict.items():
...     rev_multidict.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)
```

Now, you're just looking for the keys in the multidict that have more than 1 value. That's easy:

```
>>> [key for key, values in rev_multidict.items() if len(values) > 1]
['Albert']
```

Except the multidict keys are the original dict values. So, this is each repeated value, not all of the keys matching each repeated value. But you know what *is* all of the keys matching each repeated value?

```
>>> [values for key, values in rev_multidict.items() if len(values) > 1]
[{'firstname', 'nickname'}]
```

Of course that gives you a list of sets. If you want to flatten that into a single list or set, that's easy. You can use `chain.from_iterable`, or a nested comprehension, or any of the other usual tricks. For example:

```
>>> set(chain.from_iterable(values for key, values in rev_multidict.items() if len(values) > 1))
{'firstname', 'nickname'}
```

Comment: Can you tell why you collected the keys in sets instead of just lists? After all, they're unique anyway.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Why _wouldn't_ you use a `set` for a set of inherently unique items that have no meaningful order? That's exactly what it's for. (Depending on what you later do with the reverse mapping, there could also be performance benefits, but there often won't be; the main reason to use it here is just that `set` is the one obvious way to represent a set.)

Comment: Hmm, good point. Sets are slower and take more memory, see [test and results here](http://ideone.com/Pzq2NK) (I think you knew, but I wanted to see numbers at least for myself). I'm used to only use sets when I actually need them. But I get your point and agree that they make more sense in a *"make sense"* way. Now I'm undecided what I would prefer.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: If you really need to micro-optimize this, write it in C. (You can definitely beat the performance of `setdefault`...) But unless this is in the hotspot of a too-slow program, or part of a library that's so general-use that you can't predict where performance might matter, you don't need to micro-optimize it.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. I expressed myself badly. The time/memory isn't *really* directly the issue, it's more that sets feel more "powerful" to me, and that to me their power feels wasted here. I think I mostly use them to uniquify stuff or to build intersections or to have fast `in` checks etc, so it seemed odd to use them without using any of that functionality. Plus I don't like writing `set()` :-). But like I said, I do get your point and I can see that *having* a set in a `set` is natural even if you don't use the potential power. I'll probably switch to sets for cases like this. Thanks.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Yeah, `set()` is up there with `(1,)` with the few "warts" on the language that really are unfortunate things about Python, rather than just a sign that the guy complaining doesn't know what he's talking about.

Answer (score 19):

I would start by flipping the keys and values:

```
flipped = {}

for key, value in d.items():
    if value not in flipped:
        flipped[value] = [key]
    else:
        flipped[value].append(key)
```

You could do this more efficiently with `collections.defaultdict(set)`. For your dictionary, `flipped` will look like:

```
{
    'Albert': ['nickname', 'firstname'],
    'Angel':  ['username'],
    'Likins': ['surname']
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This method does not require neither external libraries nor an `if` statement:

```
reverse_dic = {}
for k, v in original_dic.iteritems():
    reverse_dic[v] = reverse_dic.get(v, []) + [k]
```

The line `reverse_dic[v] = reverse_dic.get(v, []) + [k]` replaces 4 lines of if-else code

Answer (score 3):

If your data set isn't too large, you don't need reverse multidict. You can use count on dict.values() and return the desired keys by iterating over dict.items().

```
desired_keys = []

vals = some_dict.values()

for key, value in some_dict.items():
   if vals.count(value) > 1:
        desired_keys.append(key)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: From Python 3, this code would not work because `some_dict.values()` does not return a list. It can be fixed by setting `vals=list(some_dict.values())`. The loop can be replaced with a list comprehension `desired_keys = [i_key for i_key, i_val in some_dict.items() if list(some_dict.values()).count(i_val) > 1]`

Answer (score 3):

Using "defaultdict":

```
from collections import defaultdict

s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in s:
    d[k].append(v)

for key, value in d.items():
    if len(value) > 1:
        print "key: %s has multiple values: %r" % (key, value)
```

Answer (score 2):

This method uses `try` and `for`.

original data

```
original_dict = {"firstname":"Albert", "nickname":"Albert", "surname":"Likins", "username":"Angel"}
```

code

```
reverse_dict = {}
for key, value in original_dict.items():
    try:reverse_dict[value].append(key)
    except:reverse_dict[value] = [key]
```

This method uses `dict.get()`.

```
reverse_dict = {}
for k, v in original_dict.items():
    reverse_dict[v] = reverse_dict.get(v, []) + [k]
```

result

```
>>> reverse_dict
{'Albert': ['firstname', 'nickname'], 'Likins': ['surname'], 'Angel': ['username']}

>>> [value for key, value in reverse_dict.items() if len(value) > 1]
[['firstname', 'nickname']]
```

Comment: imho, it would be much better to catch KeyError explicitly