# Two key with same value to one key in python

Tags: python, dictionary

In one dictionary, I want to merge the keys with same value.

To go from

```
d = {'a' : '100', 'b' : '100'}
```

to

```
d = {'a;b' : '100'}
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672238/find-dictionary-keys-with-duplicate-values

Comment: And why not `'b;a'`? Because dictionaries are order-less, you can't really do this.

Comment: How about inverting the dict ? Store the dict as: `{100: ['a', 'b']}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
d = { 'a': 100, 'b': 100, 'c': 10 }

tmp = {}
for key, value in d.items():
  if value in tmp:
    tmp[value].append(key)
  else:
    tmp[value] = [ key ]
print tmp # {10: ['c'], 100: ['a','b']}

e = {}
for value, keys in tmp.items():
  e[';'.join(keys)] = value

print e # {'a;b': 100, 'c': 10}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a comprehension, join the keys in alphabetical order if they have a value equal to the given value.

```
combo = {';'.join(sorted(k for k in d.keys() if d[k] == v)): v for v in set(d.values())}
```