# Returning keys from dictionary based on matching values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I just started working with dictionaries in Python and could use help with making a program that uses a dictionary and takes a user's input to return keys that match based on values.

The idea is that the user provides a key name that is already a key in the dictionary. What would return are the names of other keys in the dictionary whose values match the values of the key searched. The values are organized into lists in the dictionary and everything is a string.

I know this will involve a loop and below is what I've tried with no success.

```
UsStrain = ""

Tru_Strains = {

        'STA' : ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
        'SD' : ['a', 'b', 'f'], 
        'GDP' : ['b', 'c', 'g'], 
        'MBR' : ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
        'BAK' : ['a', 'b', 'c']
}



for Stains in Tru_Strains:

    UsStr = input("Enter a strain: ")

    print(Tru_Strains[UsStr])
```

Ex:
If a user put in the key "STA" as an input what would be returned are the keys MBR and BAK because the values are an exact match. Any insights would help.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672238/find-dictionary-keys-with-duplicate-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work fine (works in linear time):

```
userInput = input("Enter a string: ")    # this is what the user enters
output = []    # output list

for key in Tru_Strains.keys():
    if(key != userInput and Tru_Strains[key] == Tru_Strains[userInput]):    # condition to check equality
        output.append(key)
print(output)    # this is the list containing your expected answer
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
    print([k for k in Tru_Strains
           if Tru_Strains[k] == Tru_Strains[UsStr] and k != UsStr])
```

If it is a large dictionary, it is probably worth doing the lookup on the user-supplied key first and storing it in a variable, because it would evaluate to the same on every iteration of the loop:

```
    val = Tru_Strains[UsStr]
    print([k for k in Tru_Strains
           if Tru_Strains[k] == val and k != UsStr])
```

Here, the iteration over `Tru_Strains` is equivalent to iterating over `Tru_Strains.keys()`.